# Not able to build cordova android projet after adding phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I receive an exception when I try to build my android cordova project. As soon as I remove the plugin the compilation works fine, when I add it again it fails with the same error.

Any help is welcome,

Thanks
Compiling the project fails with error

mbopat-2:$ cordova build android

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/patrick/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at 

build_9h46slmadmegn4opsdieo7cxy.run(/Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/Projects/ALMAMobile/platforms/android/build.gradle:147)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.
Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/Projects/ALMAMobile/platforms/android/google-services.json
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebugDex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper;

com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragStartHelper;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
 FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Cordova CLI version and cordova platform version
Cordova 8.1.2
Cordova-Android 6.4.0

```
code-push 2.0.6 "CodePushAcquisition"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.11.13 "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 2.0.1 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 2.0.1 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.2 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.0 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.0 "Toast"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova-support-google-services 1.2.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.2 "PushPlugin"
```

Comment: Start with updating cordova android version to `android 7.1.1`. Dex errors could be tricky to resolve. Most likely some plugins are conflicting. Do you need to scan barcodes, or just QR codes ?

Comment: I just need to scan qr codes.will try to update to 7.1.1

Comment: Try this plugin `cordova-plugin-qrscanner` I use it for all apps I need qr scanner and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that different plugins in your project (e.g. `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`, `phonegap-plugin-push`, `cordova-plugin-background-geolocation`) are specifying different versions of the Android Support Library, causing a conflict when Gradle comes to resolve dependencies during the Android build process.

You can use the [cordova-android-support-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release) plugin to override the versions they specify and align to a single version which should fix the build failure, for example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+
```

Comment: Looks better, but still having a related problem when building for android now getting A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
"> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "11+"

Comment: thankyou, been trying other solutions for past 24 hours, i suspect caused by phonegap-plugin-push. this works.